What do you call someone who keeps changing their mind?
What's the name to designate someone who keeps changing their mind? I'm looking for a noun, not an adjective.
Examples:

He changed his mind for the 5th time. What a _____!
My friend is _____. He'll likely change the project's direction again in a few days.


if you could write a sentence showing us how you would use the word that would be helpful

@Mari-LouA "He changed his mind for the 5th time. What a _____!" ; "My friend is _____. He'll likely change the project's direction again in a few days."

I would call someone like that a vacillator.

Some ideas:
weathercock:

a person or thing that changes readily or often

flip-flopper. (Informal) (Collins English Dictionary — Complete & Unabridged 2012 Digital Edition:

a person who makes a complete change of policy, opinion, etc


Note that the word vacillator ([ vas-uh-ley-ter ])

someone who is indecisive or irresolute. Example:
People prefer an unequivocal position from their leaders; vacillators do not inspire confidence.

is not a good choice, as TimR
commented

"to change your mind" is to take a position opposite the one you held previously, whereas a vacillator is someone who cannot make up their mind, that is, who cannot reach a decision or a position.


"to change your mind" is to take a position opposite the one you held previously, whereas a vaccilator is someone who cannot make up their mind, that is, who cannot reach a decision or a position.

@TimR thanks, good point

Fickle (adj)
marked by lack of steadfastness, constancy, or stability : given to erratic changeableness
Or
Wishy-washy (adj, informal)
lacking in character or determination

A very informal word in American English is wishy-washy. For example,
My friend is wishy-washy. He will probably change his mind in a couple of days.
